# configure: error: Can not link to libboost_atomic

Tags: c++, boost, configure

I am trying to compile some code. I installed boost using

```
brew install boost
```

which successfully completed. I then ran

```
autoreconf --install
```

which then allowed me to run

```
./configure
```

however it generates an error looking for `libboost_atomic`:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
checking for boostlib >= 1.60... yes
checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_thread-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::Log library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_log-mt... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_log_setup-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::Filesystem library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_filesystem... yes
checking whether the Boost::Program_Options library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_program_options-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_system... yes
checking whether the Boost::Chrono library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_chrono-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::Regex library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_regex-mt... yes
checking whether the Boost::Date_Time library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_date_time-mt... yes
checking for main in -lboost_atomic... no
configure: error: Can not link to libboost_atomic!
```

Searching on the internet has not yielded any information (I'm a user of the software, not a developer, so I'm not sure I'm looking for the right terms).

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Do I need to install further dependencies?

The system is Mac 10.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the package for developing with the boost atomic library. This is a common problem when compiling stuff on Linux, and your fix is to always Google the library (boost atomic) and your linux flavor, to see what to get. For Debian based systems (e.g. Ubuntu),

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-atomic-dev
```

should fix this. You may get other such errors - rinse and repeat. If all else fails you can download the source, and compile and install that:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/atomic.html

You have make instructions there.

Comment: Thanks - any idea what I should be looking for on a mac? Homebrew only seems to have `boost` and nothing else (`brew install libboost-atomic-dev` doesn't work). I have downloaded the boost source from http://www.boost.org/users/download/ - if I compile and install this, should it install `libboost_atomic`? I hesitate to just go ahead and try in case I end up with two conflicting installations of boost (one through homebrew, and one compiled directly).

Comment: @Gerhard I think it should, from the description. In any case remove the homebrew installation before you try. Then you can always go back if it fails.

Comment: @Gerhard I think it was introduced in 1.52, so perhaps the homebrew version was to old.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that. For your information, brew installs boost-1.64.

Comment: @Gerhard that's newest, odd then. Maybe it's missing a flag in the compilation.

Comment: Installation from source (`./bootstrap.sh` and `sudo ./b2 install`) makes it work, without uninstalling the homebrew version. Thank you so much for your help!